# Downloading multiple files one by one using AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I'm trying to download multiple files one by one (file is downloaded, we start downloading the next file). Using this method I can keep track of the files being downloaded. The problem is that I'm using the following code for executing a Task:

```
                File file = null;                
                for(int i=0; i< videos.length; i++) {
                     file = new File(root.getPath() + videos[i]);
                     boolean exists = file.exists();
                     if(exists){
                         //tv.append("\n\n"+fileNames[i]+" already exists");
                         continue;
                     }
                     else {
                         currentFile = videos[i];
                         new DownloadFileAsync().execute(videoURL+videos[i],videos[i]);            

                     }
                     file = null;
                }
```

As you can see, I call new DownloadFileAsync().execute(videoURL+videos[i],videos[i]); in a loop which obviously start a task for each of the files and downloads them simultaneously.

**My question is**: How can I run execute the task for a specific file, check if it has been downloaded-  if yes, proceed with next file by executing a task for it?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Can you help me out? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096781/for-loop-does-not-doing-my-async-task-completely/16099854?noredirect=1#16099854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to download all the files at the same tim e(simultaneously) but one by one (serially). 
In order to do so build a String array with the URLs to download, and call `execute()` with that array.

> Example: Assuming that your `DownloadFileAsync` expects String as a
>   parameter to it's `doInBackground method`, you would call to:

```
new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url1, url2, url3, url4, video1, video2, video3, video4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I replace the entire loop with the line you provided and inserted my URLs and video names in there too accordingly but it doesn't seem to download the files at all and notification bar doesn't show up anymore. The other problem is how am I going to track the files as one of the main reasons why I want to do this serial downloading is so that I can track the files downloaded. So that in case of network connectivity problems I can resume download from the last file. Another reason is to save memory.

Comment: I hear that some people are using IntentService and are somehow queuing the downloading in a FIFO fashion. That's exactly what I'm looking for but I have no idea how to go about doing it!! I'm wondering maybe I should take my download code and file saving code which is in my doInBackground(String ...url) method inside AsyncTask and copy it in the onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) method ... would that work!!

Comment: you don't need DownloadFileAsync if you are using AsyncTask ... as it's already asynched ... just send a notification after each download completed ... but you are on the right track

Answer (score 5):

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    // File url to download
    String[] ur = {
            "http://www.funrocker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Animals-Wild-Life-Jungle-FunRocker.Com-03.jpg",
            "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-j56yaqpfjVE/TnzTjcqnCjI/AAAAAAAAGPM/MzqmczFkC30/s1600/natural-pictures.jpg",
            "http://www.fantasy-and-art.com/wp-content/gallery/nature-wallpapers/red-tree-wallpaper-hd.jpg" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(ur);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < f_url.length; i++) {
                    URL url = new URL(f_url[i]);
                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                    conection.connect();
                    // getting file length
                    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                            url.openStream(), 8192);
                    System.out.println("Data::" + f_url[i]);
                    // Output stream to write file
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                            "/sdcard/downloaded" + i + ".jpg");

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                        publishProgress((int) ((total * 100)/lenghtOfFile));

                        // writing data to file
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    // flushing output
                    output.flush();

                    // closing streams
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/downloaded.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            // my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HI @sharma i am using download manger in this case i cannot loop thru the url.please help me!

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.ProgressDialogDemo1;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ProgressDialogDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ProgressBar prgBar1;
    ImageView imgv1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imgv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
        startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        prgBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgBar1);
        prgBar1.setMax(100);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    startDownload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDownload() {
        String[] url = {"http://animal.discovery.com/birds/peacock/pictures/peacock-picture.jpg",
                    "http://www.funrocker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Animals-Wild-Life-Jungle-FunRocker.Com-03.jpg",
                    "http://www.thewallpapers.org/photo/5790/Nature_Wallpapers-037.jpg",
                    "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-j56yaqpfjVE/TnzTjcqnCjI/AAAAAAAAGPM/MzqmczFkC30/s1600/natural-pictures.jpg",
                    "http://www.fantasy-and-art.com/wp-content/gallery/nature-wallpapers/red-tree-wallpaper-hd.jpg",
                    "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg/300px-Bachalpseeflowers.jpg"};
        DownloadFileAsync dloadFAsync = new DownloadFileAsync(url);
        dloadFAsync.execute(url);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    //              Async  Task
    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        int current=0;
        String[] paths;
        String fpath;
        boolean show = false;

        public DownloadFileAsync(String[] paths) {
            super();
            this.paths = paths;
            for(int i=0; i<paths.length; i++)
                System.out.println((i+1)+":  "+paths[i]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int rows = aurl.length;
                while(current < rows)
                {
                    int count;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Current:  "+current+"\t\tRows: "+rows);
                        fpath = getFileName(this.paths[current]);
                        URL url = new URL(this.paths[current]);
                        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                        conexion.connect();
                        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 512);
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+fpath);
                        byte data[] = new byte[512];
                        long total = 0;
                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
                        show = true;
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        current++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
            }   //  while end
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            prgBar1.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            if(show) {
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File imgFile = new File(dir, getFileName(this.paths[(current-1)]));
                Bitmap bmp  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imgv1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                show = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            System.out.println("unused: "+unused);
        }
    }

    public String getFileName(String wholePath)
    {
        String name=null;
        int start,end;
        start=wholePath.lastIndexOf('/');
        end=wholePath.length();     //lastIndexOf('.');
        name=wholePath.substring((start+1),end);
        name = "images/"+name;
        System.out.println("Start:"+start+"\t\tEnd:"+end+"\t\tName:"+name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: here, i have taken array of images url, which i have passed to async task. In async task, in doInBackground method , i've taken while loop of size of url's array. Here I have downloaded files and stored in sd-card. I also hav used Progress Dialog to update progress-bar; which is updated in onProgressUpdate and also previous downloaded image is shown from sd-card.