# How to use AsyncTask to download files?

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask

I'm Using this class to download files:

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {
    String downloadUrl;
    LocalBroadcastManager mLocalBroadcastManager;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/org.test.download/");
    double fileSize = 0;
    DownloadAsyncTask dat;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public DownloadService(String url,Context c, ProgressBar pBar){
        downloadUrl = url;
        mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(c);
        progressBar = pBar;
        dat = new DownloadAsyncTask();
        dat.execute(new String[]{downloadUrl});

    }

    private boolean checkDirs(){
        if(!dir.exists()){
            return dir.mkdirs();
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void cancel(){
        dat.cancel(true);
    }
    public class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String fileName = downloadUrl.substring(downloadUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                if(!checkDirs()){
                    return "Making directories failed!";
                }
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir,fileName));
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    int percentage = 0;
                    double downloadedSize = 0;
                    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
                    {
                        if(isCancelled()){
                            break;
                        }
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                        percentage = (int) ((downloadedSize / fileSize) * 100);
                        publishProgress(percentage);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Download Failed",e.getMessage());
                }
                if(isCancelled()){
                    return "Download cancelled!";
                }
            return "Download complete";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
            super.onProgressUpdate(values[0]);
            if(progressBar != null){
                progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            }else{
                Log.w("status", "ProgressBar is null, please supply one!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent("org.test.download.DOWNLOAD_STARTED"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String str){
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent("org.test.download.DOWNLOAD_FINISHED"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent("org.test.download.DOWNLOAD_CANCELLED"));
        }

    }

}
```

I'm using this because apparently `DownloadManager` wont work prior to `API 9` and i'm targeting `API 7`

I have `ListView` which parses a XML File and shows packages that can be downloaded.

How can I modify this class to accept Array of strings containing URLs and download them one by one ?

Or is there any good way to download List of files ?

Comment: Your answer may stay here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660963/downloading-multiple-files-one-by-one-using-asynctask

Answer (score 2):

Look into using an IntentService. The thread in an IntentService runs in the background, which means you don't have to handle all the mess of thread handling.

IntentService kills off its thread once its done, so you have to persist the data.

To communicate back to your Activity, use a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Can you provide me sample code ?