# How to properly connect for getting multiple files from server?

Tags: android

I'm working on my first android app and I have this silly problem.
I've read there: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html that I can pass multiple arguments (urls here) to method like this:
*.execute(url1, url2, url3);
And then use urls like typical array.
But when I'm trying this I only get first url used. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong in here. Does anyone knows something useful?

**UPDATE:** Using Log.d I noticed that everything about passing urls and getting data works fine, but after connect() method to second url it stops. I think I don't close connection/disconnect and that's why it's not working. I looked into reference, but there is nothing about disconnecting.
Here's my code:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 TextView cpuT;
 TextView ramT;
 TextView uptimeT;
 TextView storageT;

List<String> ram = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> cpu = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> uptime = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> temperatures = new ArrayList<String>();


public class NetThread extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
                int count = urls.length;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    URLConnection conn = urls[i].openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        data.add(line);
                    }
                    in.close();
                        if (urls[i].getFile().equals("/ram")) {
                        ram = data;
                        ramT.setText("");
                        for (String x : ram)
                            ramT.setText(ramT.getText() + x + "\n");
                    }

                    else if (urls[i].getFile().equals("/cpu")) {
                        cpu = data;
                    }

                    else if (urls[i].getFile().equals("/uptime")) {
                        uptime = data;
                        uptimeT.setText("");
                        for (String x : uptime) {
                            uptimeT.setText(uptimeT.getText() + x + "\n");
                        }
                    }

                    else if (urls[i].getFile().equals("/storage")) {
                        storage = data;
                        storageT.setText("");
                        for (String x : storage) {
                            storageT.setText(storageT.getText() + x + "\n");
                        }
                    }

                    else if (urls[i].getFile().equals("/temperatures")) {
                        temperatures = data;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cpuT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayCpu);
    ramT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayRam);
    uptimeT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayUptime);
    storageT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayStorage);

    URL ramUrl = null;
    URL uptimeUrl = null;
    URL storageUrl = null;
    try {
        ramUrl = new URL("http", "192.168.0.111", 1984, "/ram");
        uptimeUrl = new URL("http", "192.168.0.111", 1984, "/uptime");
        storageUrl = new URL("http", "192.168.0.111", 1984, "/storage");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NetThread netThread = new NetThread();
    netThread.execute(ramUrl, uptimeUrl, storageUrl);
}
}
```

Comment: ' data.add(line);'. What is data? Why isn't that a local variable of the urls for loop? Where are you 'resetting' it for the second and third file?

Comment: data is List of strings. It's created every single iteration in for-loop. You can see declaration of it just below "try {" code around 15 line. It's text which I get from server. Basicaly raw data of cpu, ram, uptime and storage stats.

Comment: Oh. And it's not variable of the urls because I've been trying to make this right (I mean - like it's showed in reference).

Comment: Sorry. I oversaw the declaration. It's ok there. Then please tell why you think only the first url is downloaded? Is the loop executed three times? Add some Log.d statements to follow the flow.

Answer (score 0):

**IntenService** and **AsyncTask** provide a single worker thread, therefore simultaneous download of multiple images is not possible. However, you could use  a **ThreadPoolExecutor** for your multiple downloads. You can create a pool of threads which are executed based on the number of files you want to download. **ThreadPoolExecutor** handles practically every aspect of threads management and its quite efficient.

Here is a code example to create an executor:

```
ExecutorService mExecutor=
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            coreSize,      // basic number of threads
            maxPoolSize,   // maximum number of threads created
            keepAliveTime,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
            );
```

And to use it:

```
mExecutor.execute(new Runnable());
```

Comment: So there is no way to first download content from first url, then second url and so on just by passing them to method?
I'm not saying that it has to be done in one time. It just has to be done.
Also thanks. I will read about it.

Comment: No way to do it only with one AsyncTask.

Comment: Nonsense. Within one doInBackground you can download as many files as you want. The AsyncTask code is in principle ok.

Comment: Then why official google reference says it's possible? Lol.
I'm not saying you're trying to cheat me, but if they show usage of 3 urls in one task and single for-loop, then I think something can be done here...

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that you want to download all images at the same time, in parallel. Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704915/3919009) post that maybe could you help you to solve this issue!

Comment: Well. It helped me just a little bit. Now my code doesn't look like it just been wiped out by a cat, but it still gives me result only of first url.
Code: http://pastebin.com/3v0zd4St
And result: http://i.imgur.com/SeRD869.png

Answer (score 0):

you can check google sample for asyc task..

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NetworkConnect

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String TAG = "Network Connect";

// Reference to the fragment showing events, so we can clear it with a button
// as necessary.
private LogFragment mLogFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);

    // Initialize text fragment that displays intro text.
    SimpleTextFragment introFragment = (SimpleTextFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.intro_fragment);
    introFragment.setText(R.string.welcome_message);
    introFragment.getTextView().setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16.0f);

    // Initialize the logging framework.
    initializeLogging();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // When the user clicks FETCH, fetch the first 500 characters of
        // raw HTML from www.google.com.
        case R.id.fetch_action:
            new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.google.com");
            return true;
        // Clear the log view fragment.
        case R.id.clear_action:
          mLogFragment.getLogView().setText("");
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Implementation of AsyncTask, to fetch the data in the background away from
 * the UI thread.
 */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          return getString(R.string.connection_error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uses the logging framework to display the output of the fetch
     * operation in the log fragment.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      Log.i(TAG, result);
    }
}

/** Initiates the fetch operation. */
private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    String str ="";

    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        str = readIt(stream, 500);
   } finally {
       if (stream != null) {
           stream.close();
        }
    }
    return str;
}

/**
 * Given a string representation of a URL, sets up a connection and gets
 * an input stream.
 * @param urlString A string representation of a URL.
 * @return An InputStream retrieved from a successful HttpURLConnection.
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(get_inputstream)
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Start the query
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
    // END_INCLUDE(get_inputstream)
}

/** Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
 * @param stream InputStream containing HTML from targeted site.
 * @param len Length of string that this method returns.
 * @return String concatenated according to len parameter.
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 * @throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
private String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}

/** Create a chain of targets that will receive log data */
public void initializeLogging() {

    // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates
    // android.util.log method signatures.

    // Wraps Android's native log framework
    LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
    Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);

    // A filter that strips out everything except the message text.
    MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
    logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);

    // On screen logging via a fragment with a TextView.
    mLogFragment =
            (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
    msgFilter.setNext(mLogFragment.getLogView());
}
```

}