# only the first file gets downloaded

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a string array and I want both files to get downloaded, but for some reason it's always just the first element of the array that gets downloaded. That first element is downloaded from dropbox correctly but I need the second one too later. Would that be better if I call preWorks() function from onCreate twice? What can be the problem?

Thanks

```
public void preWorks() {
    asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params) {

            int count = 0;
            String[] txt_files = {"/l12.txt", "/l13.txt"};

            for (String fileName : txt_files) {

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/do" + fileName);

                String response = "";

                if (!(file.exists())) {
                    //file doesn't exist!!

                    AndroidAuthSession session = null;
                    try {
                        session = buildSession();
                    } catch (DropboxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dropboxAPI = new DropboxAPI<>(session);


                    Dir.mkdirs();

                    File fileDB = new File(file + fileName
                            .substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')));
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDB);
                        TextDownloader.dropboxAPI.getFile(fileName, null,
                                outputStream, null);
                        return null;
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (DropboxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                BufferedReader br;

                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
                            FileInputStream
                            (file), "cp1252"));
                    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;
                         response += line + '\n');

                    count = response.length() - response.replace(";", "").length();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

                String preFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 4);

                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(TextDownloader.this)
                        .edit()
                        .putString(preFileName, response).apply();

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            Toast.makeText(TextDownloader.this, "your file has been downloaded", Toast
                    .LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(TextDownloader.this, MainActivity.class);
            TextDownloader.this.startActivity(intent);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //tv1.setText("your file is getting downloaded");
            Toast.makeText(TextDownloader.this, "your file is getting downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    };

    asyncTask.execute();

}
```

Comment: I think this solution might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660963/downloading-multiple-files-one-by-one-using-asynctask